# How can I preserve js comments just where they are with closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

Is there a way to tell closure compiler to preserve a comment just in the place it is. I tried using @preserve, but it moves the comment to the top of the file.

Answer (score 3):

No - that's not supported (except in `WHITESPACE_ONLY` mode).

The compiler should preserve the order of JSDoc comments which are marked with either `@preserve` or `@license`, but they are moved to the top of the file.

In general, comments are for human readability. Closure-compiler optimizes for code size and execution.

Comment: I can't even accomplish that in WHITESPACE_ONLY mode

Comment: "comments are for human readability"? What about IE's conditional compilation comments, source maps comments and all the other kinds of comments one would like to keep?

Comment: IE Conditional Comments: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Using-Conditional-Compilation-With-Closure-Compiler  Source map comments are best handled as a post-build step.

Answer (score 0):

though not as pretty, you can use labels on just about any block to survive all known packers, minifiers, and as you mentioned, closure:

for example:

```
(function(){
function cstr()     {return arguments[0].toString()}
function val()      {return parseFloat(arguments[0])}


_:"simulate an API call, returning a number between 0 and 1";
function getInfo(){
  return Math.random();
}



function cint()     {return parseInt(arguments[0])}
function rnd()      {return Math.random()}


return getInfo;
}());
```

which closure turns into:

```
(function(){"simulate an API call, returning a number between 0 and 1";return function(){return Math.random()}})();
```